# How to sort list from two Model Class

Tags: java, list, sorting, android-recyclerview, collections

I have a `RecyclerView` that use Two lists to show data, and i need to sort this data with two fields.

- the first field from the first model class `(EX StudentModel.class)`;
- the second field from the second model class `(EX SchoolModel.class)`;

Here i have two model class. This is my code.

**The first one:**

```
public class UploadResultOfExamModel {
    public static Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel> TopresultComparator = new Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadResultOfExamModel o1, UploadResultOfExamModel o2) {
            StringBuilder firstPercentage = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder secondPercentage = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < o1.getPercentage().length(); i++) {
                char d = o1.getPercentage().charAt(i);
                if (d != '%') {
                    if (d == '.') {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        firstPercentage.append(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < o2.getPercentage().length(); z++) {
                char d = o2.getPercentage().charAt(z);
                if (d != '%') {
                    if (d == '.') {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        secondPercentage.append(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            String frst = String.valueOf(firstPercentage);
            String scnd = String.valueOf(secondPercentage);
            int first = 0;
            int second = 0;
            if (!frst.equals("") && !scnd.equals("")) {
                first = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(firstPercentage));
                second = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secondPercentage));
            }
            return first - second;
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel> TopdateComparator = new Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadResultOfExamModel o1, UploadResultOfExamModel o2) {
            return o1.getDate().compareTo(o2.getDate());
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel> ToplevelComparator = new Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadResultOfExamModel o1, UploadResultOfExamModel o2) {
            return o1.getLevel().compareTo(o2.getLevel());
        }
    };


    public static Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel> ButtomresultComparator = new Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadResultOfExamModel o1, UploadResultOfExamModel o2) {
            StringBuilder firstPercentage = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder secondPercentage = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < o1.getPercentage().length(); i++) {
                char d = o1.getPercentage().charAt(i);
                if (d != '%') {
                    if (d == '.') {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        firstPercentage.append(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int z = 0; z < o2.getPercentage().length(); z++) {
                char d = o2.getPercentage().charAt(z);
                if (d != '%') {
                    if (d == '.') {
                        break;
                    } else {
                        secondPercentage.append(d);
                    }
                }
            }
            String frst = String.valueOf(firstPercentage);
            String scnd = String.valueOf(secondPercentage);
            int first = 0;
            int second = 0;
            if (!frst.equals("") && !scnd.equals("")) {
                first = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(firstPercentage));
                second = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(secondPercentage));
            }
            return second - first;
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel> ButtomdateComparator = new Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadResultOfExamModel o1, UploadResultOfExamModel o2) {
            return o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel> ButtomlevelComparator = new Comparator<UploadResultOfExamModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadResultOfExamModel o1, UploadResultOfExamModel o2) {
            return o2.getLevel().compareTo(o1.getLevel());
        }
    };


    String level, result, percentage, color, date;

    public UploadResultOfExamModel() {
    }

    public UploadResultOfExamModel(String level, String result, String percentage, String color, String date) {
        this.level = level;
        this.result = result;
        this.percentage = percentage;
        this.color = color;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void setLevel(String level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getPercentage() {
        return percentage;
    }

    public void setPercentage(String percentage) {
        this.percentage = percentage;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

**The second one:**

```
public class UploadStudentInformationModel {


    public static Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel> TopWilayaComparator = new Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadStudentInformationModel o1, UploadStudentInformationModel o2) {
            return o1.getWilayaNumber() - (o2.getWilayaNumber());
        }
    };


    public static Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel> ButtomWilayaComparator = new Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadStudentInformationModel o1, UploadStudentInformationModel o2) {
            return o2.getWilayaNumber() - (o1.getWilayaNumber());
        }
    };
    public static Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel> TopAgeComparator = new Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadStudentInformationModel o1, UploadStudentInformationModel o2) {
            return o1.getBirthDay().compareTo(o2.getBirthDay());
        }
    };

    public static Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel> ButtomAgeComparator = new Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadStudentInformationModel o1, UploadStudentInformationModel o2) {
            return o2.getBirthDay().compareTo(o1.getBirthDay());
        }
    };


    public static Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel> CoachNumberComparator = new Comparator<UploadStudentInformationModel>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(UploadStudentInformationModel o1, UploadStudentInformationModel o2) {
            return o1.getCoachNumber() - o2.getCoachNumber();
        }
    };


    String fullName, username, password, wilayaName, mokataa, birthDay, active, photo, schoolName;
    int coachNumber, studentNumber, wilayaNumber;

    public UploadStudentInformationModel() {
    }

    public UploadStudentInformationModel(String fullName, String username, String password, String wilayaName, int wilayaNumber, String mokataa, String birthDay, String active, String photo, String schoolName, int coachNumber, int studentNumber) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.wilayaName = wilayaName;
        this.wilayaNumber = wilayaNumber;
        this.mokataa = mokataa;
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
        this.active = active;
        this.photo = photo;
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
        this.coachNumber = coachNumber;
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public int getStudentNumber() {
        return studentNumber;
    }

    public void setStudentNumber(int studentNumber) {
        this.studentNumber = studentNumber;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getWilayaName() {
        return wilayaName;
    }

    public void setWilayaName(String wilayaName) {
        this.wilayaName = wilayaName;
    }

    public int getWilayaNumber() {
        return wilayaNumber;
    }

    public void setWilayaNumber(int wilayaNumber) {
        this.wilayaNumber = wilayaNumber;
    }

    public String getMokataa() {
        return mokataa;
    }

    public void setMokataa(String mokataa) {
        this.mokataa = mokataa;
    }

    public String getBirthDay() {
        return birthDay;
    }

    public void setBirthDay(String birthDay) {
        this.birthDay = birthDay;
    }

    public String getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(String active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(String photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getSchoolName() {
        return schoolName;
    }

    public void setSchoolName(String schoolName) {
        this.schoolName = schoolName;
    }

    public int getCoachNumber() {
        return coachNumber;
    }

    public void setCoachNumber(int coachNumber) {
        this.coachNumber = coachNumber;
    }
}
```

So how i can sort the adapter list with **Result** field and **WilayaNumber** field?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of 2 object and you want to store it you need to check wich object copare to which .
So let we have a list of objects.
List = new ArrayList<>()
And pass any data to from class 1 and 2.
To Sort it you need to make comparable class for the list not inside the class or make sort in its own class seperated  or out of 2 classes .
Be cause may by your list compare class 1 by class 2 so you implementation dosent handle this case .

As following code you can sort this list and handle a 4 cases.
May be o1 from class 1 and o2 from class 2
May be o1 from class 2 and o2 from class 1
May be o1 and o2 feom class 1
Or o1 and o2 from class 2
You can remove Integer.compare and return your own value or compare any values

```
'ArrayList<Object> coll = new ArrayList<>();
    coll.add(new Model_1(20));
    coll.add(new Model_1(30));
    coll.add(new Model_1(3));
    coll.add(new Model_2(10));
    coll.add(new Model_1(7));
    coll.add(new Model_2(12));
    coll.add(new Model_1(40));
    coll.add(new Model_2(50));
    coll.add(new Model_2(50));

    Collections.sort(coll, new Comparator<Object>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

            if (o1 instanceof Model_1 && o2 instanceof Model_1) {
                return Integer.compare(((Model_1) o1).getNum_1(), ((Model_1) o2).getNum_1());
            }else if(o1 instanceof Model_2 && o2 instanceof Model_2){
                return Integer.compare(((Model_2) o1).getNum_2(), ((Model_2) o2).getNum_2());
            }else if(o1 instanceof Model_1 && o2 instanceof Model_2){
                return Integer.compare(((Model_1) o1).getNum_1(), ((Model_2) o2).getNum_2());
            }else if(o1 instanceof Model_2 && o2 instanceof Model_1){
                return Integer.compare(((Model_2) o1).getNum_2(), ((Model_1) o2).getNum_1());
            }
            return 0;

        }
    });

    for (Object parentClass : coll) {

        if (parentClass instanceof Model_1) {
            System.out.println("model _1 " + ((Model_1) parentClass).getNum_1());
        } else if (parentClass instanceof Model_2) {
            System.out.println("model _2 " + ((Model_2) parentClass).getNum_2());
        }
    }'
```